# In Flask: How to access app Logger within Blueprint

Tags: python, logging, flask

What is the standard way for a blueprint to access the application logger?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Inside the blueprint add:

```
from flask import current_app
```

and when needed, call:

```
current_app.logger.info('grolsh')
```

Comment: As far as I understand, this will only work during a request?

Comment: I have added the code inside my blueprint routes file, but there is neither logging to the console or a file.

Answer (score 28):

Btw, I use this pattern:

```
# core.py
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy
from flask import current_app

logger = LocalProxy(lambda: current_app.logger)


# views.py
from core import logger

@mod.route("/")
def index():
    logger.info("serving index")
    ...
```

Comment: What's the point of your code?

Comment: @Arthur - I think it's setting things up so that you'd only need to write "logger.info" rather than "current_app.logger.info".

Answer (score 0):

In main(init).py file declare

```
dictConfig(
    {
        "version": 1,
        "formatters": {
            "default": {
                "format": "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s | %(module)s] %(message)s",
                "datefmt": "%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S",
            },
        },
        "handlers": {
            "console": {
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "formatter": "default",
            },
            "file": {
                "class": "logging.FileHandler",
                "filename": "ivt-trace.log",
                "formatter": "default",
            },
        },
        "root": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["console", "file"]},
    }
)
```

and in blueprint files :

```
import logging
from flask import current_app

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# define the blueprint
blueprint_xxxx = Blueprint(name="blueprint_xxx", import_name=__name__, url_prefix='/xxxx/yyyy')

def some_func():
logger.info(msg="some logging info")
```

This worked for me.