# VSCode python type hint complaning when None

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, linter

On some functions with type hint, when many type can be return, and if None is available

```
(method) get_instance: (config_dict: Unknown) -> Self@DBConnector | None
```

if it use it

```
    db_obj = DBConnector.get_instance(configUtil.config)
    connection = db_obj.get_connection()
```

db_obj.get_connection() is in red, and the message when i mouse over is

> Cannot access member "get_connection" for type "None"
> Member "get_connection" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

I tried to find content on this, but found nothing

Comment: I would suggest adding `if db_obj is not None` to your code. The bug is not in the type checker, but in your own code. Pylance is correct

Comment: Ok, i did what you say, and it works, i was not aware about this, but now, it seems obvious for me (after you showing me the light), but i have other issue where pylance is complaining. I think it's legit, but somehow i don't understand the issue ```Cannot access member "info" for type "list[str]"
  Member "info" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
info: Unknown | Any``` using ```current_app.logger.info("show me the money") ```

Comment: looks like your `current_app.logger` is documented as `list[str]` instead of `logging.Log` or something similar

Comment: i agree with you, but i applied this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994174/in-flask-how-to-access-app-logger-within-blueprint . From what i've understand, current_app is a proxy to the "main" application which should declare somehow the logger. But in my case, i dont have it declare in the main program, this could be the issue, i'll still digging

Answer (score 0):

Found fix on [this https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/371](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/371)

this is due on how pylance behave : [enter link description here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)

i've edited my vscode config

> "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off"